# Command for setting unnamed RGB colors?

Tags: color

Is there any command for setting the "output" color providing its RGB values, i.e., without having to define a name for the color first?

Comment: Using `\textcolor` as an example, usages `\textcolor{red}{text}` and `\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{text}` are both supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\color[rgb]{1,0,0} red

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer is OK, ... but for naive people like me it is insufficient:

Answer (score 0):

The comment does not accept code so I write it here (Note this is only a comment, the answer is OK of course)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0} {red}

The line below will give :
! Package color Error: Argument `62' not in range [0,1].See the color package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... 
%
\begin{verbatim}
\textcolor[rgb]{62,114,196} {Medium Blue} 
\end{verbatim}
Using a color picker, rgb is usually given in integer between 0 and 255 so you have to use RGB *upper case*:
\begin{verbatim}
\textcolor[RGB]{62,114,196} {Medium Blue}
\end{verbatim}
\textcolor[RGB]{62,114,196} {Medium Blue} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `textcolor` by `color`.